Incomplete support for webp images on chat
Recently support was added for webp images across all the network.
Yet, chat was left out. As a result, webp images used in chat do not get oneboxed like other images.
I don't know if this is a small change or something that would require a complete rewrite of the chat picture oneboxing feature (hopefully the former), but I am posting this reminder here so that the issue can be tracked.


I don't know if this is a small change

No, it's not. It is two small changes 
I had to add webp to two lists of image extensions: In the front-end code so you get the three little blinking dots when you post a link with that extension, and in the backend code so that it actually gets oneboxed.
Works now, thanks! (You have to reload your chat room to get the three dots.)


I suspect its not that webp isn't supported but other image types have the ! added automatically. The images can be inline - but they're not, and they should be. Its something that actually does need changes to how chat handles things but its probably not going to be as bad as a complete rewrite of the chat picture oneboxing feature.
